# Problem with include guard

Tags: c++, visual-c++, inclusion

When I add an include guard to my header file for a Visual C++ project, it gives me the following warning and error:

> warning C4603: '_MAPTEST_H' : macro is not defined or definition is different after precompiled header use
>
> Add macro to precompiled header instead of defining here
>
> .\MapTest.cpp(6) : use of precompiled header** // the precompiled header stdafx.h is included in this line
>
> .\MapTest.cpp(186) : fatal error C1020: unexpected #endif

but when I add the precompiled header before the include guard, no warning or error is emitted. What is the reason for this?

Comment: Can you post the minimum amount of code that reproduces this problem?

Comment: Identifiers that start with an underscore and are followed by another underscore or capital letter are reserved, don't use them.

Comment: #ifndef _MAPTEST_H
#define _MAPTEST_H
#include "stdafx.h"

_MAPTEST_H is the inclusion guard name. When I put precompiled header before the macro defintion, works fine.

Comment: sorry for not-so-readable posting :(

Comment: @GMan: Thanks, that seems to be it :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Two problems I can think of:

1. According to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precompiled_header#stdafx.h), Visual C++ won't compile anything before the line where you include `stdafx.h` - so that line needs to be the very first one in the file. If you put it after the macro definition, it gets skipped, hence the errors you're seeing.
2. Identifiers starting with a leading underscore and a capital letter (or double leading underscores) are reserved, which might be causing a name conflict. see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier/228797#228797) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Try opening stdafx.cpp and add your macro definition there!
I hope your problem is solved